# Downloading image file from server (Spring controller) using angulajs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am trying to build image download functionality. I have following code in 
angularJs controller

```
$scope.download= function(){                                                                                                
     smoothingFilterService.downloadImage($scope.imageObj.destinationPath).then( function (data, status, headers, config) {  
               var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');                                                                         
               anchor.attr({                                                                                                 
                     href: 'data:application/jpg,' + data.data,                                                              
                    target: '_self',                                                                                         
                       download: data.headers.filename                                                                       
               });                                                                                                           
               angular.element(document.body).append(anchor);                                                                
               anchor[0].click();                                                                                            

     },function (error) {                                                                                                    
     })                                                                                                                      
 }
```

Code in angular Service

```
downloadImage:function(filePath){
            var req={
                method:'GET',
                url:'/iprocessor/downloadImage',
                params: {filePath: filePath},
                transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
                    var response = {};
                    response.data = data;
                    // take note of headers() call        response.headers = headers();
                    return response;
                }

            }
            return $http(req)

        }
```

Html Code

```
 <a class=" small"  href="" ng-click="download()">Download </a>
```

Backend java controller code

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/downloadImage",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
      public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadImage(@RequestParam String filePath, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
          response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=sharp.jpg");
          File file= new File(filePath);
          FileSystemResource fileResource = new FileSystemResource(file);
          byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(fileResource.getInputStream()));
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.add("filename", fileResource.getFilename());
          return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(base64Bytes);
      }
```

When I hit the download link, it downloads the file with name 'download' without any extension. I was expecting file  'sharp.jpg'.

[image]

Http Request call

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg") ?

Comment: @apandey846 yes, same result

Comment: Sometimes double quote also required with filename in content disposition header like this  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sharp.jpg\""). Try this